# Constructing a mesh from triangle data (plane, svec, tvec)

Tags: binary-analysis, c++, binary-format

I am trying to obtain some mesh data from a game which stores its collision surfaces for props/models in an array of "CollTri" structures which looks like this (taken from the limited source code I have access to):

```
struct CollTri
{
  vec4_t plane;
  vec4_t svec;
  vec4_t tvec;
}
```

It's parent structure for reference is "CollSurf".

```
struct CollSurf
{
  CollTri *collTris;
  int numCollTris;
  vec3_t mins;
  vec3_t maxs;
}
```

How would I go about interpreting these "CollTri" structures and converting them into a triangle list for easy mesh creation? It's unclear to me what "svec" and "tvec" is and I'm not great at 3D math. The game is based off the Quake III engine so that might help.

I have dumped some of the data here for reference:
http://pastebin.com/UABAjDQP